npx create-react-app myapp does not work, gives error "Unknown command: "install$1$1"
npx create-react-app myapp does not work, gives error Unknown command: "install$1$1.

No error, with this command. Maybe mention the version along with the command.
For example,
npx create-react-app@5.0.1 test-application


Have you installed the actual npm package?
npm i shadcn

This part wasn't very clear in the docs for me, but doing this fixed it
